# Twilio Chat - The authorization with Token failed in Javascript SDK

Tags: twilio, twilio-php, twilio-programmable-chat

I am generating the token using PHP SDK. The token signature is verified in jwt.io. All the keys are correct.

While creating the chat client, it throws error.

> ems.us1.twilio.com/v1/token  a status of 401 (Unauthorized)
>   EMS E:
>   Error: The authorization with Token failed
>   media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/chat/releases/2.2.0/twilio-chat.min.js:241

Attached screenshot shows the token data from jwt.io.

[image]

Comment: Is the `exp` time still within the current time when you try to authorize? Does the Account Sid that you are using have access to the Chat Service?

Comment: Yes to both questions. Meanwhile, I created a twilio function to generate token. The chat client works perfectly with the token received from twilio function.

Comment: Oh, that's odd. Wonder what's going on with the PHP helper then. Would you be able to raise an issue on the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php/) so that it can be investigated?

Comment: I raised a support ticket to twilio with the php code and keys. I assume they are investigating it.  I have also noticed in another thread that Video client fails with the token generated from PHP server.  Not sure it is related.

Comment: That might well be related, thanks for raising that. :)